# SQL combine all data by date

Tags: sql

I am trying to combine all the data by the date. Its sales data with promotional codes and without. I have tried:

```
SELECT Order Date, sum(Promo Code), sum(Sales Amount)
FROM Data
```

Is this possible in SQL?

Data

```
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| Order Date    | Promo Code | Sales Amount | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20  |   50         |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20  |   50         |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |   pc20     |   25         |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |            |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |            |   25         |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

What I want to happen

```
Output
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Order Date    | Promo Code         | Sales Amount | 
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20, vip20   |   150        |  
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20            |   100        |   
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20          |   50         |  
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20            |   50         |   
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   null             |   50         |   
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |   null             |   25         |
+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

I am not sure this is even possible....

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You want to group by both columns:

```
SELECT Order_Date, Promo_Code, sum(Sales Amount)
FROM Data
GROUP BY Order_Date, Promo_Code;
```

Comment: @PanDora . . . Yes, it does.  It treats them as a single group.